# Sequence labeling In Latex

Tags: equations

In a sequence {1, 2, 3, ...}, I want to write under each term a down arrow and label them as x_1, x_2, etc.  How do I do that? 
I have tried matrix commands and array commands. It does not give me the correct form.  Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) loaded, it may be easier to use `$\{x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots\} = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$`, since stacking under/over elements will cause problems with line-spacing.

Answer (score 4):

I hope that one of the following interpretations is close to your expectations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{*5{c}}
1&2&3&\ldots&n\\[-2pt]
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow& &\downarrow\\[-2pt]
x_1&x_2&x_3&\ldots&x_n
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{*5{l}}
1&2&3&\ldots&n\\
\downarrow_{x_1}&\downarrow_{x_2}&\downarrow_{x_n}& &\downarrow_{x_n}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\{
\stackunder{1,}{\stackunder{\downarrow\,}{\scriptscriptstyle x_1}}\,
\stackunder{2,}{\stackunder{\downarrow\,}{\scriptscriptstyle x_2}}\,
\stackunder{3,}{\stackunder{\downarrow\,}{\scriptscriptstyle x_3}}\,
\ldots
\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one does not like the look of subscripting in `\scriptscriptstyle`, here is an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\stackMath
\def\sss#1{\scalebox{.8}{$\scriptstyle#1$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\{
\stackunder{1,}{\stackunder{\downarrow\,}{\sss{x_1}}}\,
\stackunder{2,}{\stackunder{\downarrow\,}{\sss{x_2}}}\,
\stackunder{3,}{\stackunder{\downarrow\,}{\sss{x_3}}}\,
\ldots
\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]